# QProcess runs process but readAll returns nothing

Tags: linux, qt, process

I am trying to start a `QProcess` by

```
QProcess process= new QProcess();
process.start("javac file.java");
```

It starts successfully and I can see the output in the Qt Creator's log window. But when I try to read it from the program using `process.readAll()`, nothing was read. But when I try to do something like

```
process.start("echo Print this message");
```

then `process.readAll()` returns "Print this message".

Can anybody help me why this happens and how can I get that work. I am trying to make a simple IDE with it.

Comment: How to make those formatting in mobile device? I am new here.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading from the process's standard output channel, but your process outputs on the standard error channel. You need to read both. You also have the option of merging them. See `QProcess` documentation - read it and make sure you understand it. Edit your question to ask for clarification if anything is unclear.